# Issue with network access with Ubuntu 14 as VMware Guest

Tags: networking, vmware

I have two virtual machines(using VMware player)

- Debian
- Ubuntu 14 Desktop

With Debian network access (company network + internet via proxy) works fine - out of the box (only configuring the proxy).

With Ubuntu I didn't manage it. I have to use the bridged (automatic) Network driver in VMWare, since NAT does not work.

I have also tried to configure the IP4 routing by using the LAN network connection properties of Windows (Gateway etc.).

But I only can ping from the Ubuntu guest system to my windows host, I cannot ping any other server (also in the internal network).

Does anybody have an idea what I could additionally try?

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to upgrade to VMware Player 7. Now it works.